Postgres - Extreme query planning times on simple query
On a 200mb table fetching entries takes forever due to high query planning times:
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, TIMING) 
SELECT id FROM tour_bookings WHERE id = 6311251;

| QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                            |
| ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| Index Only Scan using tour_bookings_pkey on tour_bookings  (cost=0.42..2.64 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=1.841..1.843 rows=1 loops=1) |
|   Index Cond: (id = 6311251)                                                                                                          |
|   Heap Fetches: 1                                                                                                                     |
|   Buffers: shared hit=4 read=3                                                                                                        |
| Planning:                                                                                                                             |
|   Buffers: shared hit=6088 read=17450                                                                                                 | 
| Planning Time: 4429.900 ms                                                                                                            |
| Execution Time: 2.973 ms                                                                                                              |

No success:

vacuuming
disabling triggers
disabling complex constraints
clustering pkey
analyse related tables

A duplicated version of the table doesn't face those issues.
Buffer access in planning seem extensive. How to find out what and why the query planner actually does?

how many tables / databases do you have?

Try vacuuming the catalog tables (in schema pg_catalog schema), or at least assessing them for bloat.

Please add the result of VACUUM (VERBOSE) tour_bookings to the question.

Do you have excessively many tables or schemas?
